# Why can't I call Context.OnFieldChanged on my own context in my component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a component AddressForm.razor that has the text boxes for an address. I use it in multiple razor pages.

I tried doing the following in it:

```
public AddressForm()
{
    _value = new AddressFormPageModel();
    Context = new EditContext(_value);
    Context.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
}
```

It never called OnFieldChanged. So I required the parent razor file to pass Context:

```
[Parameter]
public EditContext? Context { get; set; }

public AddressForm()
{
    _value = new AddressFormPageModel();
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Context!.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
}
```

That works. But why can't I have my own Context in the child component that gets called for `OnFieldChanged`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have:

```cs
<EditForm EditContext="myEditContext">

//....

<AddressForm />


</EditForm>
```

And within AddressForm you have:

```cs
<EditForm EditContext="myAddressContext">
...

// input controls

</EditForm>
```

What you have is:

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="myEditContext">


<CascadingValue Value="myAddressContext">

// Any input controls in here have two `EditContext` objects cascaded to them.  I think they get assigned the first
</CascadingValue>



</CascadingValue>
```

You can't have multiple cascaded `EditContext`s.

Comment: Does the `Context` come from the `EditForm`? If so, then this all makes sense. And in that case, without explicitly declaring anything, is there a way for AddressForm to get the Context it is executing under? TIA

Comment: See - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/2120c62f6b5c067523bf92f60818dfc7cef36dbf/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/EditForm.cs#L153 .  If you want the main cascaded `EditContext` just get the CascadingParameter in `AddressForm`

Comment: As always, thank you very much.